# Custom AlertView With Background

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uikit, uialertview

Everybody, I need to set one image on UIAlertView..

[image]

I have attached my UIAlertview with image prob..

i have used this code lines..

```
UIAlertView *theAlert = [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Atention"
   message: @"YOUR MESSAGE HERE", nil)
   delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil] autorelease];

   [theAlert show];

   UILabel *theTitle = [theAlert valueForKey:@"_titleLabel"];
   [theTitle setTextColor:[UIColor redColor]];

   UILabel *theBody = [theAlert valueForKey:@"_bodyTextLabel"];
   [theBody setTextColor:[UIColor blueColor]];

   UIImage *theImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Background.png"];    
   theImage = [theImage stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:16 topCapHeight:16];
   CGSize theSize = [theAlert frame].size;

   UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(theSize);    
   [theImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, theSize.width, theSize.height)];    
   theImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();    
   UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

   [[theAlert layer] setContents:[theImage CGImage]];
```

please solve this issue.. 
i need only image with alert..

Comment: IMHO - I'd stab my eyes out if I saw that kind of alert view...

Comment: So, please you have any idea than solve my issue..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this...

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"UIAlert View" message:@"hello" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:@"Close",nil];

UIImage *alertImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"plus.png"];

UIImageView *backgroundImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:alertImage];

backgroundImageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 282, 130);

backgroundImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;

[alert addSubview:backgroundImageView];

[alert sendSubviewToBack:backgroundImageView]; 
[alert show];
[alert release];
```

Comment: You can still see the outline of the default image when it's closing.

Answer (score 4):

You should consider to not use UIAlertView, but have your own AlertView see [TSAlertView](https://github.com/TomSwift/TSAlertView) for an alternative implementation, that is not derived from UIAlertView.

TSAlertView is allowing you to set your own background image.

---

Another solution **that I am not recommending** could be:

You can use [introspection](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Introspection.html): Loop over the UIAlertViews subviews, identify the one that holds the background image set it hidden and place your own backroundimage at an index below/over the original image view.

---

I found this project: [Subclass UIAlertView to customize the look of an alert](http://joris.kluivers.nl/iphone-dev/?p=CustomAlert). It is not working for iOS 4.2+, but with my introspection idea you can make it work again:

change the `-layoutSubviews` of `JKCustomAlert` to:

```
- (void) layoutSubviews {
    for (UIView *v in [self subviews]) {
        if ([v class] == [UIImageView class]) {
            [v setHidden:YES];
        }
    }
    alertTextLabel.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
    [alertTextLabel sizeToFit];

    CGRect textRect = alertTextLabel.frame;
    textRect.origin.x = (CGRectGetWidth(self.bounds) - CGRectGetWidth(textRect)) / 2;
    textRect.origin.y = (CGRectGetHeight(self.bounds) - CGRectGetHeight(textRect)) / 2;
    textRect.origin.y -= 30.0;

    alertTextLabel.frame = textRect;

    alertTextLabel.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(- M_PI * .08);
}
```

**I am NOT promising, that this trick will work in future versions of iOS**

Comment: Apple doesn't want the style of UIAlertView to be altered. Using a custom AlertView is the cleanest approach.

Comment: Thanks for updating me with apple guide line... But its possible to make alert view like adding image as specially for iphone game...

Comment: see my latest edit. it is using an subclass of UIAlertView, what should be absolutely ok for you. But if you dont want to subclass, you can do the trick on a regular UIAlertView just before you show it.

Answer (score 0):

A solution I like to use for this is to add a UIView to the ViewController, which mimics the appearance of an alert.
The other property of a UIAlertView is that no other part of the app can be used until the alert is dismissed. This can easily be mimicked by making your UIView a subview of another UIView (with a clear background), which takes up the entire screen.

If you don't want to implement that yourself, here's a Custom Alert View class you could use: https://github.com/shivsak/CustomAlertView