# How to customize UIAlert View..?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uilabel, uialertview

I have customized the `UIViews` by adding images to make it look like radio button or check boxes, but for my spec I want to make the `UIAlertView` look like this...

[image]

Can anyone suggest how to do this?
Thanks!

Comment: You can customize alert view but iTunes reject your App...

Comment: @Vishal are You sure...?

Comment: That’s terrible UI. You should use UIActionSheet instead.

Comment: Yes i am sure...You can googling it...

Comment: @zoul credits goes to our designers :)

Comment: Guys how about customize the normal UIView look like above .......

Comment: just scale UIAlertView and add your desired UI

Comment: UIActionSheet should be used for such purpose instead. App with UIAlertView like on your picture will be rejected by iTC review team, because it violate Human Interaction Guides for iOS. If it's not a problem, then you can customize code for your needs from https://github.com/eaigner/CODialog

Comment: You're using UIAlertView for the wrong reason. It is there to "alert" the user that something has happened. Not for the user to bring up themselves and do something with it.

Comment: "The UIAlertView class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified." see http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There’s [many previous questions about this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=uialertview+customize), one of them links [this component](https://github.com/gpambrozio/BlockAlertsAnd-ActionSheets) that lets you create custom alerts and action sheets. Might be a good way to start.

Comment: @NikitaP **The UIAlertView class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified.**

Comment: @MilKyWaY: true, but who is asking you to subclass it. just addsubview over it. It is perfectly acceptable. I have got an app accepted (on 20Jan'13) in which i have added subviews over alertview to modify it

Comment: @NikitaP Nobody is asking you to subclass it! Just pointed it out to make you aware if you are not. Adding subview is not a bad idea..

Comment: @NikitaP can you share a screenshot of an alertview customised by adding subviews?

Comment: Please note that the linked library on GitHub *does not* subclass `UIAlertView` or `UIActionSheet`, it’s a reimplementation and as such it should be perfectly safe on the App Store.

Comment: check out this [image](http://i45.tinypic.com/2n74ll5.png)
and for info on how i created that: check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6692943/1554632)

Comment: @NikitaP thanks a ton! this is interesting, let me try out the same idea

Comment: @NikitaP so will you get that default Ok button click action?

Comment: @MilKyWaY I think, there is a default button action for all the buttons, until you specify any action in the delegate method.

Comment: @NikitaP yeah, I know that..but how wil we get that button action if a subview is loaded over it? In this image, is this button also a subview?

Answer (score 1):

You can design custom view and can give animation to it as alert view using this code

```
    -(void)initialDelayEnded 
{

    alert_upload.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 0.001, 0.001);
    alert_upload.alpha = 1.0;
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1/1.5];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(bounce1AnimationStopped)];
    alert_upload.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 1.1, 1.1);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

- (void)bounce1AnimationStopped {
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.5/2];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(bounce2AnimationStopped)];
    alert_upload.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 0.9, 0.9);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

- (void)bounce2AnimationStopped {
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.5/2];
    alert_upload.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
    [UIView commitAnimations];


}
```

alert_upload is UIView.

Answer (score -1):

You can create your own customized alert views, Apple wont reject it until unless user interaction.