# How to show image in alert as bigger image on tap in ios swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uialertview

In my app, on tapping the image, I want to show the image as a bigger one. Is it possible to do it in alert view or any other method.

I am adding `UITapGestureRecognizer` to `UIImageView` and set `UserInteractionEnabled` as true

```
let imageTap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "imageTap")
self.createrImage.addGestureRecognizer(imageTap)

  func imageTap() {

    let alertView = UIAlertView(title: "Alert", message: "", delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
    let imvImage = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 30, y: 50, width: 100, height: 100))
    imvImage.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit
    imvImage.image = myImage

    alertView.setValue(imvImage, forKey: "accessoryView")
    alertView.show()
}
```

When the alert shows I am seeing the image in full size.I want it in custom size.[Full Size Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9j4LP.png)

If I add `alertView.view`, am getting the error as follows:

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2KtRY.png)

Comment: On iOS7+ UIAlertView not allowed to `-addSubview:`. You should use custom alertview for this purpose..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6692361/custom-alertview-with-background

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this

```
func imageTap() {

    let alertView = UIAlertView(title: "Alert", message: "Alert + Image", delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
    let imvImage = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
    imvImage.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.Center
    imvImage.image = UIImage(named: "image_name")

    alertView.view.addSubview(imageView)
    //alertView.setValue(imvImage, forKey: "accessoryView")
    alertView.show()
}
```

Comment: Hi, it works but the alert view is stretched to the full display size. How can I set the size of alert view? I already tried `alertView.frame`

Comment: I tried that, yet the size of alert view did not change

Comment: @AAA i had seen your image it seems like you need to add subview `alert.view.addSubview(imageView)` instead of  `alertView.setValue(imvImage, forKey: "accessoryView")` and set image size smaller

Comment: What is the `alert` here? If I use `let alert = UIAlertView()` the error says 'UIAlertView does not have a member view'

Comment: please check the edited question. (Image). Maybe is it because I am using Swift 2?

Comment: @AAA you can use `UIAlertViewController` will fix your issue

Comment: check this link https://github.com/wimagguc/ios-custom-alertview , http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-fundamentals-uialertview-and-uialertcontroller--cms-24038

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to go for a better solution than use a alertView. If what you want to do is to have bigger view when tapped on a image view, there are plenty of good libraries available.

```
https://github.com/jaredsinclair/JTSImageViewController
https://github.com/NYTimes/NYTPhotoViewer
https://github.com/gonzalezreal/Vertigo
```

They are very straight forward to use and have as cocoa pods.

Comment: They are all in ObjC! Any Swift library?

Comment: If you are using cocoa pod , just add them as pods and xcode will create bridge for you. Or you can create a bridge your self. Almost all the libraries available out there with obj-c can be used in swift with a bridging header